# how to write a single row cell by cell and fill it in csv file

Tags: python, pandas

I have a CSV file that only has column headers:

```
 cat mycsv.csv
 col_1@@@col_2@@@col_3@@@col_3
```

I have to fill a single row with `None` values in each cell of the CSV file. Can someone suggest me the best-optimized way to do that in Python and Pandas?

After I fill the row the csv file should look like:

```
 cat mycsv.csv
 col_1 , col_2 , col_3 , col_3
 0@@@None@@@None@@@None
```

How to insert index and separator is `@@@` instead of `,` ? I am getting an error as:

```
tmp.to_csv(csvFile,sep='@@@',index=True) 
 , line 1381, in to_csv
formatter.save()
 3.6.1/linux_x86_64/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/formats/format.py", line 1473, in save
self.writer = csv.writer(f, **writer_kwargs)
  TypeError: "delimiter" must be a 1-character string
Exception ignored in: <module 'threading' from Traceback (most recent call last):
File python-3.6.1/linux_x86_64/lib/python3.6/threading.py", line 1015, in 
_delete
del _active[get_ident()] 
KeyError: 140459817715712
```

Comment: Rather than searching for the most optimised approach, have you made progress in implementing any approach? Please show what you have got from your research so far.

Answer (score 0):

Does it a `@` or `,` ? If you using a formal csv file, the separator of the header should be the same as the contents.

If you mean `,`, you could use something like that.

```
import pandas as pd
# just for abrevation
tmp = pd.read_csv("mycsv.csv",sep=',')
tmp.loc[0,:] = "None"
tmp.to_csv("mycsv.csv",sep=',',index=False)
```

If you mean `@`, I suggest that you should not use pandas. Just using the simply `IO` ways.

```
tmp = open("mycsv.csv","r").read()
tmp = tmp + "\n" + "@@@".join(["None"] * len(tmp.split(',')))
with open("mycsv.csv","w") as f1:
    f1.write(tmp)
```

Answer (score 0):

What you are trying to do is rather non-standard. First read the the first line in as the header and split it using your `@@@` delimiter. Next open an output file and write this header using `,` as a delimiter. Next write your `row` using the `@@@` delimiter. For example:

```
row = [0, None, None, None]

with open('mycsv.csv') as f_input:
    header = next(f_input).strip().split('@@@')

with open('mycsv2.csv', 'w') as f_output:
    f_output.write(' , '.join(header) + '\n')
    f_output.write('@@@'.join(map(str, row)) + '\n')
```

If `mycsv.csv` contains:

```
col_1@@@col_2@@@col_3@@@col_3
```

Then `mycsv2.csv` would be written as:

```
col_1 , col_2 , col_3 , col_3
0@@@None@@@None@@@None
```