# How to solve the delimiter error while using to_csv function in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

This is a followup question on [how to write a single row cell by cell and fill it in csv file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52494495/how-to-write-a-single-row-cell-by-cell-and-fill-it-in-csv-file)

```
 import pandas as pd
 delim = "@@@"
 # just for abrevation
 tmp = pd.read_csv("mycsv.csv",sep='@@@')
 tmp.loc[0,:] = "None"
 tmp.to_csv("mycsv.csv",sep=delim,index=False)
```

I am getting follow error . Please suggest some correct solution

```
self.writer = csv.writer(f, **writer_kwargs)
TypeError: "delimiter" must be a 1-character string
Exception ignored in: <module 'threading' from 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  line 1296, in _shutdown
 _main_thread._delete()
File /share/python-3.6.1/linux_x86_64/lib/python3.6/threading.py", line 1015, 
in _delete
del _active[get_ident()]
KeyError: 140613724829696
```

Comment: Show us your csv file.

Answer (score 0):

As per the `Error` and the [to_csv](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.to_csv.html) documentation, it supports only one character.

Whereas [read_csv](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html) supports `str`. That's why it works why reading and failing at writing. You might need to change the delimiter to one character.